# If $A + B$ is nonsingular, so is $(A+c\cdot B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In this example, $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, and $A+B$ is nonsingular, i.e. $(A+B)x = 0$ has only the trivial solution $x = 0$.

Does this logically imply that $(A+cB)x = 0$ has only the trivial solution also (where $c$ is a non-zero scalar)?

I have proved that if $B$ is nonsingular, then $cB$ must also be nonsingular, as the $c$ scalar can be interpreted as a series of type II EROs which don't affect the linear independence of matrix rows, but I can't see a way to prove the above.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "linearly independent matrix." It is the columns of the matrix that are linearly independent. You could say the matrix has full rank.

Comment: Since $A+cB=A(I+cA^{-1}B)$, it is nonsingular if and only if the polynomial equation $\det(I+cA^{-1}B)=0$ is not solvable for $c$.

Answer (score 6):

Counterexample: Let $A=I$, $B=I$, $c = -1$

Comment: In general, as long as $A=-cB$, where $B$ is any non-singular matrix and $c$ isn't $0$ or $-1$, we've got a counterexample. The one in this answer is particularly simple. :)